# File Accessing(Deleting/Opening) in Android 3.0 and above

Tags: android, android-file

I'm facing an issue with HoneyComb's File System.
Firstly,I'm clearing files in  a directory.And after deleting, if i make any operations again in that directory an eception saying  **java.io.IOException: Device or resource busy** is happening.The exception has never happened in 2.2 or 2.3 OS.

The code i'm using to delete files in a directory is

```
public static void emptyTheDirectory(File file){

if(file.exists()){
    if(file.isDirectory()){                         //dir
        File childrenFiles[] = file.listFiles();
        if(childrenFiles.length != 0){
            for(File childFile : childrenFiles){

                emptyTheDirectory(childFile,isLoggingOut);      //delete subFodler/file
            }//end for 
        }
    }

    try{
        //If the file is folder, by now all files in folders are deleted.

        boolean bool = file.delete();               //delete file

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Am i doing anything wrong?
Is there any safer way to access file system in android?

Please suggest.

**Update**

After applying the above code to the root folder,I observed the root folder created by application is changed to a file with same name and the installed file managers are also not able to delete the file.

Regards,
Sha.

Comment: Any ideas???...I'm in an urgent requirement...